# Start batch file from terminal and pass a specific argument

Tags: batch-file, command-line-arguments

I have a batch file with the following code which is starting a jarfile.

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT EXIST jarFile.jar GOTO ERROR
IF EXIST jarFile.jar Start java -jar jarFile.jar

ECHO Successfully started!
PAUSE
EXIT

:ERROR
ECHO Jar file doesn't found!
PAUSE
EXIT
```

I would like to ask you when i start the bat file from CMD prompt, to use a parameter "-force" which can skip the pause after starting it.
Example: start someBatFile.bat -force(the new parameter) and when it is used the "-force" parameter  i want to skip the pause. Is it possible to do that and if it is can you help me ?

Comment: Replace `pause` with `Echo=%*|Findstr /i "-force" 2>&1>Nul ||pause` this checks if `-force` appears anywhere in the arguments - if not then `pause`

Comment: `IF NOT [%1]==[-force] PAUSE` --- See syntax here: https://ss64.com/nt/if.html

Comment: This question has nothing to do with `java` or `jar`, it's about conditional logic in a Windows Batch file based on arguments to the batch script. Removing tags!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line with PAUSE to the following:

```
IF NOT !%1!==!-force! PAUSE
```

Comment: Yes thats the answer i needed. Thanks a lot buddy :) I know that the %1 means the first argument but can you explain me why is captured by this "!" and the force command or show me a source where i can read for it

Comment: Why are you using exclamation points instead of quotes? There's no variable called -force.

Comment: It should read `if /I not "%~1"=="-force" pause` (remove `/I` in case it is case-sensitive)...

Comment: @SomethingDark only what i'm used to. You're right that quotes are better. And aschipfl does it even better and ensures that quotes in the parameter won't hurt.